# How to initialize a static field of which type is a private nested class?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, private, friend

*Outer.hpp*:

```cpp
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    Inner() {}
  };
  static Inner inner;
}
```

*Outer.cpp* (at top-level, e.g. not within a function body):

```cpp
Outer::Inner Outer::inner;
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2248: 'Outer::Inner::inner' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Outer::Inner'
```

I'm not using a compiler that is fully compliant with C++11 (Visual Studio 2010), so it is not possible to define the field at declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to make `Outer` a friend of `Inner`:

*Outer.hpp*:

```cpp
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    Inner() {}
    friend Outer;
  }
  static Inner inner;
}
```

Now, `Outer` can see `Inner`'s type as if it weren't private even in the implementation file, so the initialization in *Outer.cpp* succeeds.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work for inner `typedef`s, as you can't specify friends for those.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to Friend it. Bad idea.

**class Inner** is a private member of **class Outer**.  There's nothing wrong with that.

The problem depends on where you've placed your definition.

```
Outer::Inner Outer::inner; // is fine in the global space.
int main()
{
    Outer::Inner Outer::inner; // Fails because it's used as a local variable to function main.
}
```

Comment: No. What does `Outer::Inner Outer::inner;` inside main function mean? See the Ideone link in my first comment. error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘Outer::inner’

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Your code (ideone) is fine.  It looks to me like Darthenius is doing something different.  Placing it somewhere out of context, like main, means he's placing the static definition in the wrong place.  If it was just a syntax prob, he wouldn't be getting the error he mentions.

Comment: I now clarified that the definition is placed at top-level.

Comment: In that case, it's complaining that the Inner's constructor is private when Outer is trying to initialise it.  A class's members are **private** by default, so Outer won't be able to create an object using that constructor.  Put in a `public:` line before the Inner constructor declaration.